# Code coloring not working correctly?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Just noticed an older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926057/1531124) of mine.

As you can see here: the first code example has "some colors", the second one that is almost identical is all just white text.

(using latest version of chrome, and dark theme on mac os)

[image: screenshot showing bad coloring in 2nd example line]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the *failure of automatic language detection* since the question has conflicting language hints (Java vs C#).

Since the code snippet is relatively short, the highlighter library *guessed* that the first code block is **Erlang**, and the second code block is... **SCSS**.

[image]

The fix is to explicitly declare the language hint on the code block.

Related feature request:

- [Improving syntax highlighting language auto-detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354793/improving-syntax-highlighting-language-auto-detection)
- [Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/stop-guessing-auto-detecting-a-language-when-you-know-it-will-be-incorrect)